# HP Printer compatibilty for Citrix PS 4.5

Tags: hp, citrix, printer

Any ideas on finding out what HP list as a compatible model with Citrix?

I used to use this:

http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA0-8465ENW.pdf (or the page it came from, and now it's gone, and this listing is out of date)

And then I found this site:

http://www.citrix.com/ready (and this appears to be out of date)

I even asked HP direct if one of their printers would work, and they never answered me.

Grrr, frustration!

(Of this is the wrong forum, I'm sorry)

Answer (score 1):

The [HP Universal PCL5](http://hp.com/go/upd) driver should be available for you to install. It will work with just about any B&W HP LaserJet printer. If you need to use a particularly old LaserJet or a Color LaserJet things get more complicated. More details are available on the document you linked from HP on page 14.

Comment: Thanks. I know all this. Unsurprisingly I've spent much time looking into it before approaching the interwebs. I want a color printer MFP. I need to know what's compatible, unfortunately the models I'm looking at are too new to be listed. The linked document has a very specific list of what HP know will and won't work. The only reason a printer shouldn't be here is because it was released after publication.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the PS and PCL6 (which both support color) drivers are somewhat unstable on the 4.x series of XA/PS. This may not be the case with newer drivers, I've not had the pleasure of trying. The CM2xxx MFPs only support TWAIN/WIA style scanning (which is generally a PITA in terminal environments). The higher end CM3, CM4, and CM6xxx series support sending to network shares and e-mail (which is much easier to support). If you're looking at DeskJet based MPFs... good luck with *that*.

Comment: I see a lot of these issues in the environment that I work in. I've found that HP universal printer drivers are somewhat buggy when used with published desktops (spooler memory leaks, server hangs, etc.). Assuming it's just with published desktops and some published applications that you're running. I'd suggest finding out if you can at least get to XA 5.5/6 and get away from the problematic Citrix PS platform.

Comment: Chris S, thanks. If I'm feeling brave I might give the PCL6 a go :/

Comment: Split71, yeah it's a published desktop. Not sure about upgrading. I may look into this. Cost will be an issue.